# State Management doesn't work after hot reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using Obx to to manage my state to build a bottom navigation bar.

```
return SafeArea(
  
  child: Scaffold(

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
      body: Obx (() =>
         _getNewSubPage()
      )),
);
```

I am calling _getNewSubPage() on index change.

```
 Widget _getNewSubPage() {
switch (homeController.currentIndex.value) {
  case 3:
    return new Container(color: Colors.blue);
  case 2:
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.green[100],
    );
  case 1:
    return new WishlistView();

  default:
    return new CategoryItemListView();
}
```

}

Code seems to work all fine on initial run and hot restart but when i hot reload views on _getNewSubPage() does not change. I also tried GetBuilder but same case was found.

code of controller

```
  final currentIndex = 0.obs;
  setBottomBarIndex(index) {
   print(index);
   currentIndex.value = index;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebuild a widget when something in its state changes you need to call the setState() of the widget. The variable is referenced to the State class and when you call setState() Flutter will rebuild the widget itself by calling the build() method of the State class.

Comment: I am using Getx architecture and using Obx to manage state and all of my views are inside statelessWidget so setState is not feasible solution to me.